# Xcode build fails with "fatal error: malformed or corrupted AST file" Crashlytics.h

Tags: objective-c, xcode, crashlytics

I recently enabled modules in my Xcode project build settings ("Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)") and now I frequently get the below build error. It works the next time I build (without any changes) but it is annoying because it happens very often (several times an hour).

> fatal error: malformed or corrupted AST file: 'could not find file
>   '/Users/mpv/dev/project/Crashlytics.framework/Headers/Crashlytics.h'
>   referenced by AST file' note: after modifying system headers, please
>   delete the module cache at
>   '/Users/mpv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/M5WJ0FYE7N06'

Crashlytics recommended removing Crashlytics.h from the precompiled header file (.pch) and importing directly in each source file that needs it. This greatly reduces the problem but I still occasionally get a Crashlytics.h file not found error when building.

```
fatal error: 'Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h' file not found
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
```

Answer (score 63):

First, try going to Product -> Clean menu in Xcode. Then rebuild when it finishes.

If that doesn't work, go to your [Name]-Prefix.pch file in the Supporting Files folder, and delete the #import  line. Build. It will have errors, it's ok, now start typing it again and make sure to select the right choice from the drop-down suggest menu so it auto-fills the rest of the line for you. (This step worked for me).

Good luck! Love it when Xcode goes weird like this :)

Comment: I got this when trying to run a trivial Unit test on a project where I'd just changed all the "int" to "NSInteger" or "NSUInteger" as appropriate. Xcode5 kept saying "delete module directory BLAH" but that had no effect - it's a bug :(. Doing a Clean fixed it.

Comment: Don't remember specifics, @binzhang, but I think I saw which line crashes, so I commented it out. Rebuild didn't work, so I added it again, this time with auto-complete (accident). It worked. So there :P

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me even though deleting derived data didn't. I wouldn't have expected that.

Comment: This worked like a charm! The solution over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984166/fatal-error-malformed-or-corrupted-ast-file-xcode did not work for me.

Comment: Removing the offending framework from my pch fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: To say I was skeptical would be an understatement. Great find.

Comment: Had the same problem with Xcode 6.4. Reinstalling it did not work, reinstalling OS X from a time machine backup neither, but forcing the rebuild by changing the .pch file contents solved it. Thanks at lot!

Comment: This is the life savior

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue after updating my version of Xcode via the Mac App Store.

After updating Xcode, the `xcode-select` Command Line Tools version of Xcode was still set to the old version. This was creating some kind of mismatch in `xcodebuild`.

I solved the issue like so:

1. `Xcode > Preferences > Command Line Tools`. Select the newest Xcode version.
2. Quit Xcode
3. Delete the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` directory.
4. Run build script again. Success!

---

For SEO purposes, when I was hitting this issue I saw the following errors:

```
error: InputFile /Users/user/source/Your-PCH-Prefix.pch 0 1406772618 191 33188... malformed line 9; 'InputFile' should have exactly five arguments
```

Also:

```
xcodebuild[53039:5503] stream error: stream error at offset 29: created by an unsupported XCDependencyGraph build
xcodebuild[53039:4e0b] stream error: stream error at offset 29: created by an unsupported XCDependencyGraph build
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Write auxiliary files
    MappingModelCompile
```