# Xcode builds with malformed error

Tags: ios, xcode, malformed

I am getting three weird errors that I never seen before.  Can anyone help me find a solution to these errors?

`Definition of CGAffineTransform (aka struct CGAffineTransform) must be imported from module CoreText.CTFontDescriptor before it is required`

> 'Unable to load module
>   "/Users/dev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/17NOBVXZ77TGU/Foundation.pcm":
>   module file out of date'
>
> Malformed or corrupted AST file: 'could not find file
>   '/Users/dev/Documents/App
>   Projects/projectname/./CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGAffineTransform.h'
>   referenced by AST file'

Comment: Quit Xcode and delete the DerivedData folder referred to in that message (_/Users/dev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/_).

Comment: @matt use "resolvable" paths... `$HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Comment: @alexgray It's his computer. It's his error message. I'm helping _him_ (or trying to). I'm using the path in his error message.

Answer (score 11):

This seems to be similar to what is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984166/fatal-error-malformed-or-corrupted-ast-file-xcode).

Deleting the folders in the `DerivedData` folder and do a deep clean with `Cmd + Shift + k`

Hope that helps,

Regards,

Michael Loo