# Fatal Error in DerivedData/ModuleCache

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

all my xcode project have this kind of error in the modulecache

```
fatal error: malformed or corrupted AST file: 'Unable to load module "/Users/FollowmeCrazy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/3C4GAENHLL37T/Darwin.pcm": module file not found'
```

I already delete the derived data in the xcode then clean it still nothing happens.

how can i resolve this?

Comment: I had same problem and solved by following this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21127748/1369955

Comment: I did simply cleaned and it does work

Answer (score 17):

You can delete Derived Data from Terminal:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

Comment: I wasted two hours then found this, thank you!

Comment: Xcode 14.3, it worked for me!

Comment: Worked on xcode 15, thanks

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode, go to Window-> Organizer ->Projects, select your project, and press the "Delete" button next to "Derived Data".

If this doesn't work, you can try Product->Clean (Cmd+Shift+k).