# iOS app runs on device but not in the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, device, simulator

I have the following problem.

I'm working on a Spritekit game at the moment.
The game runs completely smooth on a iPhone5. When I want to run the app in the simulator, the compiler tells me:

```
fatal error: malformed or corrupted AST file: 'Unable to load module "/Users/macvideo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/3TAGE798UH20R/Darwin.pcm": module file not found'
note: after modifying system headers, please delete the module cache at '/Users/macvideo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/3TAGE798UH20R'
```

But when I want to run it with the 64bit simulator it works, the framerate is very low but there are no errors. (The game also runs very smoothly with the iPhone5s).

I do not own a iPhone 4 to test the game on a device. But also here, the compiler tells me an error like the one above when I want to run the app with the simulator for the iPhone4!

Can I ignore that when the game runs completely without any problems on a real device or do I have to care about these errors?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: do what the message says or ignore simulator

Comment: are you using any static Library in your modules

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984166/fatal-error-malformed-or-corrupted-ast-file-xcode

Answer (score 3):

try clearing derived data from xcode.
select Xcode -> window-> organizer->Projects  then select and delete your project derived data.

Answer (score 0):

try to restore the content and settings of your simulator. I had a similar problem some time ago and after simultor restore all was ok.