# iOS app builds on device, but not Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have an iOS app that fails to build on Simulator when the configuration is set to 'Release'. 'Debug' builds fine. Additionally, both 'Release' and 'Debug' configurations build on a real device. In Xcode, the error is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_BMWAnalytics", referenced from:
 objc-class-ref in BMWManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried resetting the simulator, cleaning the project, and deleting derived data. What is causing this error and how do I fix it? A similar question is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880948/ios-app-runs-on-device-but-not-in-the-simulator), but does not seem to include the discrepancy between 'Debug' and 'Release'.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you doing a Release build against the simulator? There's no point for that. Use debug builds to do some basic testing but real Release builds should to be tested on real devices.

Answer (score 0):

That error just means that the code that provides the BMWAnalytics class is not being linked into your executable.

You need to make sure that the BMWAnalytics class's @implementation is provided by a file included in your target (or in a library that your target links against).