# malformed or corrupted AST file: 'Unable to load module "/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/34OBPFY26OANR/Darwin.pcm": file not found'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, macos

I am using OSX 10.9.3 in my Mac Mini and XCode 5.0.2.
When I execute my project as iPhone retina (3.5 inch) and iPhone retina (4.0 inch) it executes smoothly without any errors but if I want to execute on iPhone retina (4-inch 64-bit), when I select this simulator there is a fatal error:

`malformed or corrupted AST file: 'Unable to load module "/Users/WeMitedMacMini1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/34OBPFY26OANR/Darwin.pcm": file not found'.`

So I am not understanding for which file Darwin.pcm it generates an error. As far I know I did not use any file named Darwin.pcm. Please help me with this error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fatal error: malformed or corrupted AST file - Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984166/fatal-error-malformed-or-corrupted-ast-file-xcode)

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode, go to Window->Organizer->Projects, select your project, and press the "Delete..." button next to "Derived data".

If this doesn't work, you can try to do a Product->Clean ( <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> ).

Answer (score 1):

you can check below cases

1) just remove your Derived data and delete all application from Simulator

2) Check if there is 64bit support

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, seemed to resolve itself after quitting and reopening XCode. Also happened to do a full system restart in between my tries, so maybe that was what did it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue is solved when I delete the product file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).